# Object iteration using for loop

Tags: php, oop, object, for-loop

Object iteration with foreach is easy:

```
foreach ($item->attributes as $attribute) {
// echo $attribute->name;
}
```

.. but I wonder if its possible to do the same with `for` instead:

```
for ($j=0; $j < count($item->attributes); $j++) {
// echo $item->attributes->$j->$name ?
}
```

Although I can create a counter outside foreach and increment it, but just wanted to know if for works for objects.

For reference, the object(s) I'm working with looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/UShw2q2z).

Comment: Yes, it will work, but why not just try it yourself?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: from pastebin, childs of `galleryInfoContainer` has private access identifiers, you can't access them outside of class.

Comment: @rjdown Thanks for that, but apparently all the examples use `foreach`, there's no mention of `for` there.

Comment: @kamalpal Maybe, but I can access it with `foreach` without any issues.

Comment: @3zzy then, you must be trying from inside of your class

Comment: It makes no difference what you use to iterate. foreach, for, while, they all work the same.

Comment: @kamalpal Probably, but my question is primarily about looping with `for` instead of `foreach`.

Comment: @rjdown I know, but just wanted to confirm if objects indeed are not iterable using `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops works for arrays which have incremented or decremented numeric index, and for associative arrays you have to use foreach unless you have separate arrays of keys, for example:

```
$count = count($keys);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $arr[$keys[$i]];
}
```

or you can reindex your assocative arrays, using `array_values`

```
$arr = array_values($assoc_array);
$count = count($arr);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i];
}
```

for objects, they are properties, which can't be start from numbers, therefore you have to convert your object to array and reindex keys.

```
$arr = array_values(json_decode(json_encode($object), true));
$count = count($arr);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i];
}
```

try to avoid above and use `foreach` instead.

Comment: Aha, just what I wanted to know. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't we collect `count()` first and store it in a variable so we don't call it upon every iteration? `for( $i = 0, $c = count($keys); ... )`

Comment: @dbf yes, you are right, I tried to cover it one line as this is just an example

Answer (score -1):

```
for ($j=0; $j < count((array)$item->attributes); $j++) {
    echo $item->attributes[$j];
}
```

Is this what you mean? You directly access this object that way, same as above, and you cast it beforehand to count.

Comment: Why are you casting $item->attributes to an array? If it's not already an array, it's not going to magically turn into one.